# HTML/CSS - Aligning text, Scrollbar Appearing

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding and I'm in the process of creating a website for my father to help build experience and a portfolio.

I'm using unsemantic & normalize.

The problems I am having are as follows;

1) I can't seem to align the bottom of the words "Michael Gilsenan" with the text in my nav bar. I have tried using the line-height property but it's behaving inconsistently and moving in all sorts of strange ways.

2) I'm trying to create a line under the header either by using the `<hr>` tag or by using the border-bottom property. Both of which eventually create a scroll bar on the `<div>` which houses my `<nav>` element.

I have been trying to find a solution for a good 4 hours and have done lots of reading. I apologise if I'm missing something obvious, I'm very tired now!

Thanks very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../external/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../external/css/unsemantic-grid-responsive-tablet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body class="grid-container">

        <header class="grid-parent">

            <div class="grid-50">
                <a href="" class="headertext">Michael Gilsenan</a>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-50">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Bio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </header> <!-- end of header-->

</body>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cacaca;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}

/* header styles */

header {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-bottom: solid #cacaca 1px;
}


header a {
    color: #332e2d;
}


.headertext {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    line-height:
}

ul li {
    display: inline; 
}

ul {
    word-spacing: 0.5em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: 1. Set the padding on your `ul` to `0`. 2. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve in #2. 3. Google 'css box model' and read for a few hours. 4. Pay special attention to how `padding`, `border`, and `margin` relate in the box model, along with your `display` values.

Comment: Hi mccambridge, I've amended the padding on `ul` as per your post but it hasn't changed. The effect I'm trying to achieve is to get the line underneath both of these; http://oi64.tinypic.com/2929u1w.jpg

Answer (score 0):

On the `ul`

```
line-height: 55px; /* match the height of the headertext. */
```

On the `header`

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wazz/ad6g2woq/63/

The trick was to find out what was causing the scrollbar. I selected the `ul` and went through the options and for `scroll` a 2nd scrollbar was added, so I new it wasn't that. Eventually I found that the scrollbar was on added on the header.

P.S. You should use a header tag `<h1>` for the `headertext` instead of making the text bigger (300%). Search engines look for header tags to understand the page (SEO). You can adjust the size of header tags in your css if it's too big or small, and still use the tag.

Comment: Thanks very much Wazz!

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is appearing because you have the **overflow** property set to **auto** in the style declaration for the **header** element:

```
header {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 80px;
  overflow: auto;                        <-- change or remove this
  border-bottom: solid #cacaca 1px;
}
```

Auto gives the browser control over what to do when the contents of a container do not fit within the dimensions of the container and will often add scrollbars where you don't intend them. Removing the overflow property or setting it to none will eliminate the scrollbar.

I am not familiar with the unsemantic stylesheet that you are using but it appears to apply a float-based layout. This makes alignment of items within a container very difficult. As an alternative, I would suggest looking into flexbox. There are a few good tutorials out there. I have used all of these and can vouch for their quality:

- What the Flexbox by Wes Bos - https://flexbox.io/
- A Complete Guide to Flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- Flexbox Froggy - https://flexboxfroggy.com/

To achieve the layout I think you are aiming for with flexbox requires the following:

Remove the unsemantic grid classes from your HTML
Replace your CSS with the following

```
* {
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* hr {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cacaca;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
} */

/* header styles */

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 80px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    /* overflow: auto; */
    /* the overflow property is setting your scrollbar. If you don't want the scrollbar, set to none : */
    /* border-bottom: solid #cacaca 1px; */
    /* Here, your properties are in the wrong order.
       it should be:
       1. border size
       2. border type/style
       3. border color. 
       Like this: */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cacaca;
}


header a {
    color: #332e2d;
}


.header-text {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    /* line-height: */
    /* When you leave in style properties with no value, this will often break your stylesheet. I've commented this out. */
}

header nav {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

I added in some comments about a few other things I noticed in your CSS. To see a working sample, you can check out this pen:

https://codepen.io/danyadsmith/pen/mKjyKQ

Normally, I would attempt to answer the question by telling you what you could do to achieve the result you want with the technologies you are using, but in this case I think the grid system you selected is causing your frustration. Flexbox is gaining adoption in modern browsers and can safely be used in projects that don't need to support legacy browsers. For more information on that, check the flexbox section on Can I Use:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Danya, thank you so much! I'm glad you said that because I was wondering if it was the unsemantic framework causing the problems so I deleted it all and will start again tomorrow taking all your advice.